# How to download specifc Libraries Ruby , Gems , and Rails and Installing them in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, installation

I have tried several time on installing Ruby on Rails on my machine . But I have failed . Now i want to Know that , is that possible to download Ruby, gems ,deV kit and Rails specficly and Installing them one by one ??

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to install specific versions of Ruby, gems ,dev kit and Rails.

This link will help: http://www.christopherirish.com/2010/08/25/how-to-install-rvm-on-ubuntu-10-04/

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove ruby on Rails, gems, devkit and install all again.
You can use this tutorial: [RubyOnRails-Community Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RubyOnRails)

or use this: [How to Install Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin) with RVM](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm)

Hope this useful.